# VNC server automatic authentication via proxy-server

Tags: websocket, vnc, novnc, websockify

I have the following scenario: There's a TightVNC server running on a machine, protected by a password. I wish to make this available for clients (in the browser), but I do not want to tell the password to the clients (nor use it in the client side at all). So, I wanted to put a proxy server between the VNC server and the client. This proxy server should do the following:

- Connect to the VNC server and authenticate itself
- Forward the websocket/VNC stream to the client who does not need to authenticate anymore.

I've been looking into websockify and noVNC, but yet to find this kind of possibility.
How could I go about this? Is this even possible?
I would prefer using Go or Typescript in the proxy side.